# F#: how to print full list (Console.WriteLine() prints only first three elements)

Tags: list, f#

Is it possible to print full list without using cycle?
I tried:

```
Console.WriteLine([1;2;3;4;5])
```

and it prints only three first elements:

```
[1;2;3; ... ]
```

Comment: Maybe this answer helps you out -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1508818/f-display-full-results-in-f-interactive-window

Answer (score 69, accepted):

If you want to use the built-in F# formatting engine (and avoid implementing the same thing yourself), you can use F# printing functions such as `printfn`. You can give it a format specifier to print an entire list (using F# formatting) or print just a first few elements (which happens when you call `ToString`):

```
> printfn "%A" [ 1 .. 5 ];;  // Full list using F# formatting 
[1; 2; 3; 4; 5]

> printfn "%O" [ 1 .. 5 ];;  // Using ToString (same as WriteLine)
[1; 2; 3; ... ]
```

If you want to use `Console.WriteLine` (or other .NET method) for some reason, you can also use `sprintf` which behaves similarly to `printf`, but returns the formatted string as the result:

```
Console.WriteLine(sprintf "%A" list)
```

The benefit of using `printf` or `sprintf` is that it also automatically deals with other F# types (for example if you have a list containing tuples, discriminated unions or records).

Comment: I noticed that "%A" with a seq<'a> will not print only a few elements (then ellipses).  I used Seq.toList to convert it to a list.

Comment: %A doesn't print the whole list: `printf "%A" [1 .. 500];;` stops at `100`.

Comment: @Clément I suspect this might have changed sometime in the last 7 years :-).

Comment: I don't think so :) AFAICT, it was already wrong back in 2009 (see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1656200/how-do-i-print-an-entire-list-in-f , which mentions the issue).

Comment: Looks like you're right. There's always `list |> List.map (sprintf "%A") |> String.concat ", " |> sprintf "[%s]"` then!

Answer (score 29):

No it's not possible to print the contents of an F# list without using a cycle / loop of sorts.  To print every element you must enumerate each of them.

In F# though it doesn't need to be done with a loop though but instead can be done with a nice pipe operation

```
[1;2;3;4;5] |> Seq.iter (fun x -> printf "%d " x)
```

And as Juliet pointed out I could simplify this further with partial application

```
[1;2;3;4;5] |> Seq.iter (printf "%d ")
```

Comment: `[1;2;3;4;5] |> Seq.iter (printf "%d ")` -- w00t, currying :)

Comment: `for x in [1;2;3;4;5] do printf "%d " x` - I actually think simple for loop would be just as good as `Seq.iter`. It of course depends, but in some situations I personally prefer the straightforward (maybe more imperative?) solution.

Comment: If it's not possible, does it mean that Tomas Petricek's answer is incorrect?

Comment: @abatischev,  @Tomas's answer is certainly correct and functional but under the hood a loop is occurring to print out the elements it's just not in the actual answer code.

Comment: @Juliet actually is not currying, is partial application :)

Answer (score 9):

In general, if you want to change as a way an printf "%A" prints your objects as a way fsi.exe shows values fo your type, you can apply StructuredFormatDisplayAttribute attribute to your type:

```
[<StructuredFormatDisplayAttribute("PP {PrettyPrinter}")>]
type Foo(a:string array) =
  let pp = Array.mapi (fun i (s: string) -> sprintf "{idx: %d len: %d contents: '%s'}" i s.Length s) a
  member x.PrettyPrinter = pp

> let foo = Foo [|"one";"two";"three"|];;
val foo : Foo =
  PP [|"{idx: 0 len: 3 contents: 'one'}"; "{idx: 1 len: 3 contents: 'two'}";
       "{idx: 2 len: 5 contents: 'three'}"|]

> printfn "%A" foo;;
PP [|"{idx: 0 len: 3 contents: 'one'}"; "{idx: 1 len: 3 contents: 'two'}";
     "{idx: 2 len: 5 contents: 'three'}"|]
val it : unit = ()
```

Comment: Interesting. Does the pretty-printer function need to be a public member?

Comment: @Joel --  it is unimportant because that property is obtained by refection API

Answer (score 1):

A perhaps more functional way of doing it:

```
let nums = [1;2;3;4;5;6]
let concat acc x = acc + " " + (string x)
let full_list = List.fold concat "" nums
printfn "%s" full_list
```

Comment: Unfortunately, string concatenation is very inefficient operation on .NET (because it needs to copy the entire string), so this may have bad performance for large lists. In .NET, the recommended way would be to use `StringBuilder` (which is mutable and makes the solution a bit less _functional_).

Comment: Also, in recent versions of F#, `List.fold_left` is called `List.fold` and you can replace `string_of_int` with overloaded `string` function.

Comment: Updated to match Tomas's comment. This language has been changing so fast lately, it's a little hard to keep up.

Comment: Yes, especially the naming! However, now that F# is a part of Visual Studio 2010 (which is almost finished), there won't be that many changes (in the language and core libraries).

Comment: Better to use String.concat.

    let nums = [1;2;3;4;5;6]

    let full_list = nums |> List.map string |> String.concat ", "

    printfn "%s" full_list